# Automate export of calendar from Outlook to Google

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, google-calendar

I use Microsoft Outlook 2013 for work and Google Calendar for everything else. I'd like to find an easy way to sync my work calendar to my personal calendar. Ideally, this would be a software application that sits in the background and automates the syncing.

**Requirements**

1. Syncing should be one-way only: Outlook to Google.
2. Must support repeating calendar items.
3. Must allow me to specify which calendar in Google to sync to. I will set up a separate calendar for work items.
4. No intermediate server. Export is direct.

**Nice to Haves**

1. Automated. Syncs in real time or regularly (say, every fifteen minutes or so).

Answer (score 2):

I found [gsyncit](http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsyncit3/index.shtml) today that can do all of your requirements. From their website:

> gSyncit is a Microsoft Outlook add-in that allows for the synchronization of Outlook calendars, contacts, notes, and tasks with your Google account. In addition, gSyncit also supports synchronization between Outlook and Toodledo, Pocket Informant Online, Evernote, Dropbox, Simplenote and Nozbe.

The plugin has a free and paid version, but the free one fulfills your requirements.