# send outlook calendar to google

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, calendar, google-calendar

I have a calendar in an outlook server for work, and I'd like to sync that calendar to my Google account so that I can see my meetings on my phone.  I've found a few solutions for subscribing to my Google calendar in outlook, but I'm trying to do the opposite of that.

I really don't care about being able to manage the calendar at all.  I just want to be able to see my work schedule somewhere other than on my laptop.  Is there an app that makes this possible?

Comment: [gsyncit](http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsyncit4/) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I recently started using gSyncit:

http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsyncit4/index.shtml

and I like it very much. From my research, it seems that there are a few other tools out there, including open source ones, but none of the others seemed very refined. There is a free trial for this tool if you want to try it out.

See this question here too:
[Automate export of calendar from Outlook to Google](https://superuser.com/questions/769729/automate-export-of-calendar-from-outlook-to-google/791223#791223)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an iPhone, and are able to setup your email on your phone, you should be able to view all calendars within the iPhone calendar. I believe windows phones operate in the same manner, I do not know how the calendar works on android operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to export your Outlook calendar to iCal and then post it somewhere public (for example, dropbox or a web site you manage).

Once you've done that then, on your phone, subscribe to the iCal feed.

The major disadvantages of this approach is that it requires your personal calendar to be accessible on the internet (which could cause a privacy issue) and that you have to update it manually.

The advantages of this approach is that your personal and work calendars have no chance of getting mixed up (as no synchronisation occurs), you can easily turn on and off viewing the calendar on the phone (handy if you go on holiday) and you don't need to install any software on your computer.